# Find Top 10% of purchased products per group then find average of those 10%

Tags: mysql, sql

Pardon my English. I'm not sure if this is possible in MySQL.

I'm trying to:

1. find the Top 10% of scores per groupid
2. then find the average
   of scores for those 10% by groupid

Sample subset of data:

```
Table name: points

groupid       score
group_001     13
group_001     12
group_001     10
group_001     12
...
group_002     12
group_002     16
group_002     19
group_002     20
group_002     12
group_002     13
...
group_003     29
group_003     21
group_003     18
...
```

...

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of your English requires pardoning?

Comment: do you need the point `1.`  ? or is it just a step to get the `2.` and you can directly pull out the avg of the 10% by groupid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it is a bit tricky . . . variables are the simplest method:

```
select group_id, avg(score)
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@g = group_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@g := group_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from points p cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @g := -1) params
      order by group_id, score desc
     ) p join
     (select group_id, count(*) as cnt
      from points
      group by group_id
     ) pp
     on pp.group_id = p.group_id
where (seqnum - 1) * 10 <= pp.cnt
group by group_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, it returned zero rows. I am using MySQL 5.7.12.

Comment: @xerlil . . . My guess is that your groups are quite small.  I changes the `where` to ensure that at least one row is in each group.